# jQuery - How to check if time stamp in the value is older than 4500 miliseconds?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to check if the value in the input is older than 4500 miiliseconds. 
How can I do that ?

html

```
<input type=hidden id="time" value="1276664400">
```

jquery

```
var currenttime = $.now();

if ($("#time").val() < currenttime) {

alert("I am older than 4500 miliseconds!");

}
```

Comment: currenttime - 4500 should do the trick

Comment: omg, why people always negative rep me.

Comment: perhaps because this isn't anything that grabbing a pencil and paper wouldn't have resolved, it's not rocket science math

Comment: I understand the professionals, however, not all questions need to be super intelligent though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var currenttime = $.now();
if ($("#time").val() < (currenttime - 4500)) {
    alert("I am older than 4500 miliseconds!");
}
```